# php include file call

Tags: php

I need to call include file more than 1000 times inside of for loop.
After 200 or 300 times completed, I am getting following error

**Warning: include(function.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Too many open files in /var/www/html/test.php**

example:

```
for($i=0;$i<=10000;$i==){
    include 'function.php';
}
```

how to fix this error?

Comment: Why would you do that? That's one of the worst things you could do. And what's in `function.php`? You need to work around that include.

Comment: why is this tagged cassandra?

Comment: try `include_once`, that will make your error go away ;) /joke

Comment: With the best will in the world, this is definitely a situation where you need to explain why you are doing what you are doing, because there must be another way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
include 'function.php'; 
for($i=0;$i<=10000;$i==){ 
  function();
}
```

Comment: Col. is suggesting you wrap function.php in a function call.  This is probably a good idea.

Comment: Or `$content = file_get_contents( 'function.php');` and in foreach: `echo preg_replace_callback( '~\{\$(.*?)\}~', $content, array( $object, 'replaceVariables'))`

Answer (score 1):

The right thing to do is to create a function in the PHP file and then call your function in the loop.

```
function something() {
    // put whatever you have inside function.php
}

for ($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) {
    // now call your function 10,000 times
    something();
}
```